# Using Open Graph meta tags to play video on Facebook Timeline

Tags: html, facebook, metadata, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to embed Flash audio players on the Facebook timeline using the `og:video` meta tags. It for some of the pages with tags buy not with others. Each page will have the same tags, except for a song id `beat_id` and `og:image`

For some of the URL's, you'll get a nice play button on the Facebook Timeline, when clicked the Flash player will open up on the timeline like a YouTube video, only for some URL's, it just displays a link.

I've tried resetting the URL's using Facebook's debugger but still the same issue. Any ideas? Here are 2 URL's and their tags, one works, the other doesn't.

Doesn't show play button, only link: http://www.myflashstore.net/share-beat/373456

```
<meta name="og:image" content="http://www.myflashstore.net/images/avatar/thumb_e14704915848de9788143522.jpg" />
  <meta name="og:video" content="http://www.myflashstore.net/flash/solo.swf?beat_id=373456&autoplay=true' />" />
  <meta name="og:video:height" content="100" />
  <meta name="og:video:width" content="400" />
  <meta name="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

Shows play button and plays on timeline: http://www.myflashstore.net/share-beat/387438

```
<meta name="og:image" content="http://www.myflashstore.net/images/avatar/thumb_37ff506f1aac87c3ff0266cf.jpg" />
  <meta name="og:video" content="http://www.myflashstore.net/flash/solo.swf?beat_id=387438&autoplay=true' />" />
  <meta name="og:video:height" content="100" />
  <meta name="og:video:width" content="400" />
  <meta name="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

**EDIT 7th May 2013**

It seems like it's a Facebook bug, I have reported the bug and it's been triaged by a FB engineer, waiting for the response

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/449237341833565

Comment: Were you able to resubmit the bug?  In the logs it looks like they said the bug will need to be resubmitted.

Answer (score -1):

this will do what you want

```
<meta name="video_width" content="700" />
<meta name="video_height" content="400" />
<meta name="video_type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<link rel="video_src" href="http://www.myflashstore.net/flash/solo.swf?beat_id=373456&autoplay=true"/>

<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.myflashstore.net/images/avatar/thumb_37ff506f1aac87c3ff0266cf.jpg" />
```

Comment: This is the old way of doing it, Facebook uses Open Graph tags now.